# Identify Onboard USB3 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, 22.04

I have a `P61A-D3` gigabyte motherboard with just 2 onboard USB3 ports. But they don't work and when I connect a USB memory, mouse or ... computer doesn't identify them. 
Also in the USB setting, there isn't any usb3 root hub. 
what should I do?

I had this problem with windows 10 and after I installed the driver, I could use ports, should I install anything like a driver in ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

When i connected my external HDD to usb3 port, HDD light turned on and it was working. It means this port is working healthy. But pc do not identify anything.

Comment: Do you remember exactly what you installed in Windows? This may give a clue about the hardware.

Comment: And, of course, feel free to [edit] the question and post your motherboard's brand/model and any other hardware specification you think might be relevant.

Comment: Motherboard model is Gygabyte P61A-D3.

Comment: I can't say exactly what i had done. Maybe after installing Ethron usb3 driver it worked.